# Make Firebase Send An Email When Uploading New Request To Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I will starts by saying that i have a background of iOS development only but i׳m capable of learning new technologies.

In my iOS app I have integrated Firebase database service in order to save request from my users. Every user can fill a form and upload to my database, I have stored all requests under "requests" from the root file system of my database.

My goal is to get alerts by mail to be sent to my email each time a new request has been uploaded.

How can I achieve that?
What new language/technologies should I learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending email is a privileged operation that you typically can't reliably do on a user's device.

So you'll likely want to run some code on an app server that reads the `requests` queue and then calls a mail service to send the actual mail.

That approach is similar to what I used in my blog [post on sending device-to-device push notifications](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html), so I recommend reading that to get an introduction to the flow. The architecture is also described in this section on [using Firebase and Google App Engine Flexible Environments](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-flexible).

[image]

Comment: I have my Nodejs project ready but can figure out how to deploy it to the app engine

Comment: That was actually the easiest part when I last tried it: `gcloud app deploy`. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine

Comment: there is an option to prevent firebase from being called the number of Childs on the node i am listen to?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provide api for web, iOS and android. If you are an iOS developer you can either use swift or objective c. I hope this help. https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it must be sent by mail